# Generate Django JWT token from inside a view

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, jwt

I'm working on a Django(1.10) project and created an api for my project using Django Rest Framework.I need to generate JWT token from inside my view.

Here's what I have tried:

Settings for REST Framework in **settings.py**:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
# Use Django's standard `django.contrib.auth` permissions,
# or allow read-only access for unauthenticated users.
'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
    'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoObjectPermissions'
],
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
    'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
),
}

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
)
```

Here is the URL to obtain a token manually:

```
    url(r'^api-token-auth/', obtain_jwt_token)
```

Here is the template from which user will request to obtain a token:

```
        <div class="col-md-9 content">
        <div class="world-map" style="width: 100%; margin-left:2%">
            <h3> Get your Authorization Token to use REST Api :</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6" style="margin-top: 20%;  margin-left: 25%;"><br>
            <form action="{% url 'users:getApiAuthToken' %}" method="post" id="getTokenForm">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <a href="" style="text-decoration: none; color: white;">
                <button type="submit" class="btn waves-effect waves-light  pull-right" value="Submit" id="enableApi" style="padding-right: 10%; font-size: 20px;"><i
                            class="material-icons left">casino</i>  Generate Api Token!</button></a>
            </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's how the ajax request will be sent:

```
    $(document).on('submit', '#getTokenForm', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: '{% url 'users:getApiAuthToken' %}',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

And here is my view where this request will process:

```
        if request.method == 'POST':
            post_data = request.POST.copy()
            post_data.update({'user': request.user.pk})
            payload = {'username': request.user.username, 'password': request.user.password}
            r = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api-token-auth/', params=payload)
            return HttpResponse('Get token auth request and data is as: {}'.format(r.text))
```

But it returns as:

> Get token auth request and data is as: {"username":["This field is required."],"password":["This field is required."]}

How can I pass current user's credentials to generate a token for him?
I need to genearte a token and send back to the user then he will be able to use this token for our rest api. How can i genearte this token inside this view?

Help me, please!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question is quite unclear, but for what it's worth, POST data is passed in via the `data` argument in Python Requests, not via `params`.

Comment: Hi @SvenMarnach, it's a view for logged in users, and exactly that's the question how should I pass the user credentials?

Comment: The reason your question is unclear is that the error message is coming form a part of the code you are not even showing, so we can only speculate what's gooing on.  That said, you can't access the current user's password.  The database only contains a hash.  You should use a function call to obtain the JWT token, not an HTTP request.

Comment: Hi @SvenMarnach, this is exactly what I need, how can I generate a token without sending an HTTP request? please! Actually here's a template which shows a button to logged in users to obtain a token for the use of our rest API, when user click on this button it will send a post request to this view in django.

Comment: Django-rest-framework does not support JWT authentication out of the box, so you must either be using some custom code to generate it, or some third-party package.  You need to figure out what you are using to generate the JWT, and then read the documentation.  With the information you provided, it's impossible to tell.

Comment: Hi @SvenMarnach, I have updated the question and add other related information, take a look, please!

Comment: So it looks like you are using a module called `rest_framework_jwt` for JWT authentication.  I googled that name for you, and it turned up the documentation for that package, which is here: http://getblimp.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/#creating-a-new-token-manually  (It's still unclear what exactly your problem was, so I'm not removing my close vote for the question.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can easily create a token manually whenever we need it, no matter from where but we just need to have the current user object accessible there.
According to the Documentation of [Django-Rest-Framework-JWT](https://jpadilla.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/#creating-a-new-token-manually) we can create a token by using this code:

```
from rest_framework_jwt.settings import api_settings

jwt_payload_handler = api_settings.JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER
jwt_encode_handler = api_settings.JWT_ENCODE_HANDLER

payload = jwt_payload_handler(user)
token = jwt_encode_handler(payload)
```

So, for this question specifically, this code will work in views as:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    jwt_payload_handler = api_settings.JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER
    jwt_encode_handler = api_settings.JWT_ENCODE_HANDLER

    payload = jwt_payload_handler(request.user)
    token = jwt_encode_handler(payload)
    return HttpResponse('Get token auth request and data is as: {}'.format(token))
```

It will return a JSON token back as the response.

Comment: What about the refresh token ?